# UWP MakeAppx 80080204 Error

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, appx, appxmanifest, makeappx

When I am packaging UWP app in x86, x64 (not including ARM) with VS 2017, the following error occurred. What should I do?

`Error info: error 80080204: All app package manifests in a bundle must declare the same values under the XPath *[local-name()='Package']/*[local-name()='Dependencies'].  The values under this XPath declared in the manifest for the package with file name "DOCompare_3.1.34.0_x64.appx" and package full name "410175959034.DOCompare_3.1.34.0_x64__8mnb09260jrwg" at line 11, column 4 don't match those declared in the manifest for the package with file name "DOCompare_3.1.34.0_x86.appx" and package full name "410175959034.DOCompare_3.1.34.0_x86__8mnb09260jrwg" at line 11, column 4.   DOCompare   D:\Project\DOCompare\DOCompare\MakeAppx`

Comment: grammar and formatting

Comment: Please check the mainifest file firstly to see if there are any errors. If no, please detail your issue with reproduce steps.

Comment: I checked, but I can't find any problem. This problem occured in my 14th packaging without editing any manifest all properties, so there might not be any reproduce steps. I'm sorry. here is my manifest file link.  [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11zUINTqDX7cc3VAkNk_Fg19o0ZjnX0wv)

Comment: "This problem occured in my 14th packaging", did you mean you can package it successful for 13 time? You should put this information in your thread. After this time failed did you have a success? And where is the manfest file link?

Comment: yes. i succeeded about 15 times. after that, i cant make a package forever...
 link is in my comment, but i'll give you a same [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11zUINTqDX7cc3VAkNk_Fg19o0ZjnX0wv). thank you.